# How to make two image sliders in one web page, like one placing in another slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://demo.code9tech.com/test/

Here is a webpage that I am developing. In this page I am trying to use two different image slider simultaniously. Please click on the `works` navigation button in this page to see how my concept look like. Hope you saw the sliders...

Here I am mentioning,
jQuery as main slider and
CSS3 as sub slider

Here I am using two different sliders of 1)jQuery and 2)CSS3
main slider is using jQuery.. and in that slider i placed a CSS3 slider..

The problem I am facing is
1)Mainly the order of two sliders ie; main slider and sub slider...

### I want to run this slider like...

First section "book printing" in that have 4 images to display in sub slider...
after that I want to move the main slider to second category "calender printing".
In that I want to display 4 images. I want to follow this on the next two categories also..

Comment: dude you're social icons are going crazy on hover

Comment: It seems to be working fine on my end. What is the problem with the order of the sliders?

Comment: @itamar problem is...the first section of main slider is ok ie; book printing. but if this coming into second section(calender printing),subslider on second section of main slider is not sliding from itz first image..i have to play the animation from first image if entered to the second section of main slider..not only for the second section.this order want to keep for all section...hope you understood..

Comment: @vipin it is sliding. Try not to hover over it. Hovering over it makes it stop sliding.

Comment: @itamar thanx for ur reponce, i fixed the problem and got the order what i think...           here is the fixed demo http://demo.code9tech.com/alpha8/